# root command from a 'set-user root' program

Tags: c, suid

I wish to start a root command from a 'set-user root' program, 
so I wrote the following C sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc > 2) {
        setuid(0);
        printf("setuid(0) executed\n");
    } else
        printf("setuid(0) NOT executed\n");

    system(argv[1]);
}
```

Testing it on Debian 6 (64 bit), I noticed that passing `"/bin/sh"` as the argument, I always get a `ROOT SHELL`, even if `argc == 2`:

```
$ gcc foo.c -o foo  
$ su  
Password: *****  
# chown root:root ./foo  
# chmod 4755 ./foo  
# ls -l foo  
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 6887 11 dic 17.44 foo  
# exit  
exit  
$ ./foo /bin/sh  
setuid(0) NOT executed  
# exit                 <<<<< ROOT SHELL  
$ ./foo /bin/sh 12345  
setuid(0) executed  
# exit                 <<<<< ROOT SHELL
```

On Slackware 14 (32 bit), it behaves differently:

```
$ gcc foo.c -o foo  
$ su   
Password: *****  
bash-4.2# chown root:root ./foo  
bash-4.2# chmod 4755 ./foo  
bash-4.2# ls -l foo  
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 6292 dic 11 17:53 foo  
bash-4.2# exit  
exit  
$ foo /bin/sh  
setuid(0) NOT executed  
sh-4.2$ exit             <<<<< USER SHELL  
exit  
$ foo /bin/sh 12345  
setuid(0) executed  
sh-4.2# exit             <<<<< ROOT SHELL  
exit
```

If I give "/usr/bin/dolphin" as argument, there is also a different behaviour.
On Debian I'm not able to get it work:

```
$ ./foo /usr/bin/dolphin  
setuid(0) NOT executed  
<unknown program name>(28884)/: KUniqueApplication: Cannot find the D-Bus session server:  "Unable to autolaunch when setuid"  
<unknown program name>(28883)/: KUniqueApplication: Pipe closed unexpectedly.
```

On Slackware, it works only if `argc == 2`, so I cannot start dolphin as root.
Why?

Answer (score 2):

To explain the slightly peculiar setuid behaviour, you need to understand that `/bin/sh` may actually be `bash`, and the default behaviour of `bash` is to drop *euid* unless it's invoked with `-p`.

This means that if you invoke bash with -p, then you should see a 'root' like shell:-

```
natsu ~> id -a
uid=1000(me) gid=1000(me) groups=1000(me),4(adm),15(kmem)
natsu ~> ./foo "/bin/bash -p"
setuid(0) NOT executed
bash-4.2# id -a
uid=1000(me) gid=1000(me) euid=0(root) egid=0(root) groups=0(root),4(adm),15(kmem),1000(me)
```

Whereas invoked without the `-p` option yields the observed behaviour:

```
pshanahan@natsu ~> ./foo /bin/bash
setuid(0) NOT executed
bash-4.2$ id -a
uid=1000(me) gid=1000(me) groups=1000(me),4(adm),15(kmem)
```

but in reality, you only have effective user id 0, not real user id 0.

getting the GUI to run in this situation... That's another matter altogether; but this should help you understand the behaviour in this case.